# Alias a bracket setter with extra parameter (index and value)

Tags: ruby, alias, brackets

I'm trying to alias a setter method with an extra parameter in Ruby. I seem to have managed to do so but I can't call the original method from within my alias.

```
# Original method
def []=(variable_id, value)
  @data[variable_id] = value
  on_change
end

# My alias
class Game_Variables
  alias :foo :[]=
  def []=(variable_id, value)
    old_value = @data[variable_id]
    foo[variable_id] = value # wrong number of arguments 0 for 2.
    on_set_variable(variable_id, old_value, @data[variable_id])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this class

```
class GameVariables
  def []=(key, value)
    # do something
  end
end

vars = GameVariables.new
```

you can call the setter in different, equivalent ways. The most common and idiomatic one is this

```
vars[:abc] = 123
```

This however is actually using syntactic sugar built into Ruby. In fact, this call actually resolves to this:

```
vars.[]=(:abc, 123)
```

This works similar for all the operators like `+`, `-`, `==` and other types of array/hash accessors. In Ruby, the whole concept of operators is just syntactic sugar that makes the Ruby parser automatically resolve certain calling constructs (like the hash setter) to their actual method calls. This however only works for some specifically named method names, one of which being `[]=`.

When you want to use the functionality of your original `[]=` method using another name, you can`t rely on the parser to resolve the syntactic sugar anymore. Thus, your call

```
foo[variable_id] = value
```

actually resolves to this:

```
foo()[variable_id] = value
```

which obviously passes to few arguments to the method. To actually be able to properly call the foo method, you can use this instead:

```
foo(variable_id, value)
```

This uses the plain old method calling syntax without any need for the parser applying any syntactic sugar.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it well. Now I understand the 0-argument error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you shouldn't use brackets when calling the original method... Not exactly intuitive but perhaps I miss something.

```
# My alias
class Game_Variables
  alias :foo :[]=
  def []=(variable_id, value)
    old_value = @data[variable_id]
    foo(variable_id, value)
    on_set_variable(variable_idx, old_value, @data[variable_id])
  end
end
```